# Open another form and then wait for that form to return a response

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a form say A that requires some input. However in order to obtain that input another form say B needs to be filled. So what i want is when a user clicks on a button in formA then formB is displayed. Now when a button in form B is clicked the result is returned to formA. What is the best way to do this. ? Currently I have a formA that just displays form B and then I am stuck . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to inherit `formB` from `QDialog` class and then to call `exec()` instead of `show()`.

From [docs](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qdialog.html#exec):

> Shows the dialog as a modal dialog, blocking until the user closes it. The function returns a DialogCode result.
>
> If the dialog is application modal, users cannot interact with any other window in the same application until they close the dialog. If the dialog is window modal, only interaction with the parent window is blocked while the dialog is open. By default, the dialog is application modal.

In conjunction with this, you may want to use `QDialog::accept`, `QDialog::reject` or `QDialog::setResult` in `formB` in order to pass result to the `formA`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you're using Qt, the simplest approach would be to use signals and slots. You could make `FormB` emit signals which contain the required data when that button is pressed. `FormA` can be make to connect to this signals and fill its form.

This example code is quite abstract, but you should be able to get the general meaning-

```
void FormA::slotButtonClicked() {
    FormB* b = new FormB(this);
    connect(b, SIGNAL(requiredData(QVariant)), 
            this, SLOT(slotFormBData(QVariant())));

    // Logic to show form B
}

void FormA::slotFormBData(const QVariant& data) {
    // Fill Form A fields with data
}

void FormB::slotButtonClicked() {
    QString data = m_lineEdit->text();
    emit requiredData(data);
}
```

If you don't want to emit all the data over signals, you can also make `FormB` emit a `done(FormB*)` signal which `FormA` can hook into and then call `FormB`'s member functions to fetch all the required data.